# Let A be a matrix Prove that A is a normal matrix if and only if ReA=f(A) for some polynomial f

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a matrix.
>   Prove that $A$ is a normal matrix if and only if $\mathfrak{Re}A=f(A)$ for some polynomial $f$.

I tired the right side

$A$ is a normal. Then there exists a unitary matrix $U$ and diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A=UDU$*

So, $\mathfrak{Re}A = U\mathfrak{Re}(D) U$*

By the *Lagrange intorpolation theorem*, there exists a polynomial of degree $n-1$, so that 
$f(ri) =\mathfrak{Re}(ri)$. Then $f(D)=\mathfrak{Re}(D)$

$$f(UDU*)=Uf(D)U*$$

So $f(A)=U\mathfrak{Re}(D)U*$

$f(A)=\mathfrak{Re}A$, but I cant't solve the left side.
May I ask for help? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have solved the more difficult part of the implication.

Note that $\operatorname{Re}(A) = \frac 1{2}(A + A^*)$. If $\operatorname{Re}(A) = f(A)$, then we have
$$
A^* = 2\operatorname{Re}(A) - A = 2f(A) - A.
$$
Since there is a polynomial $g$ for which $A^* = g(A)$, we have $A^*A = AA^*$. So, $A$ is indeed normal.